# How can i define proof environment?

Tags: environments, proof-package

I need something like proof environment from amsthm, but with word "důkaz" (proof in my language) at start of environment. How can I define such environment?

Thanks for help.

Comment: You don't need one, just redefine `\proofname` (if you use babel or similar, you will probably need to add it to your language, which will be another question that are already on this site)